# Any significant advantages to using column vectors instead of 1D column matrices in Armadillo?

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, vector, armadillo

I'm exclusively using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) matrices in my C++ code for both 2D and 1D arrays for the sake of simplicity and ease of maintenance. For instance, I make use of the vector initializer list
but immediately convert it to a matrix before it is actually used:

```
mat bArray = mat(colvec({0.1, 0.2, 0.3}));
```

Most of my code consists of 1D arrays and there are only a few places where I truly need the 2D Armadillo matrix.

Would I gain a significant performance increase if I converted all (nx1) Armadillo matrices to (nx1) Armadillo column vectors? Are there any other nuances between these two data structures that I should know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `arma::vec` is the same as `arma::colvec` and they are just typedefs for `Col<double>`. You can see this in the `typedef_mat.hpp` file in armadillo source code. Also, `arma::Col<T>` inherits from `Mat<T>`, as can been seem in the `Col_bones.hpp` file. Essentially, a `colvec` is just a matrix with a single column. You wouldn't gain anything, except that you would avoid the unnecessary copy from the temporary vector to the matrix. Although maybe that is a move, since the colvec is a temporary, and thus even that gain could be marginal.

Nevertheless, if you want a 1D array use a `colvec` instead of `mat` at least for the sake of being clear about it.

Comment: Thanks @darcamo! I guess I should focus on speeding up other parts of the code instead. By the way, I use your `gdb_armadillo_helpers` package all the time. It is really helpful!

Comment: Thanks. Implementing pretty printers for armadillo classes was my main motivation to learn a lot about gdb and armadillo source code.